# How to handle multiple instances of a model on one view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model class called DeviceType that is something like this:

```
public class DeviceType
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    String Type { get; set; }
    String Description { get; set; } 
    EntityCollection<AttributeDefinition> AttributeDefinitions { get; set; }
}
```

AttributeDefinition is defined like this:

```
public class AttributeDefinition
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    String Name { get; set; }
    bool IsPrivate { get; set; }
    bool IsInherited { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to create a view to edit the details for a DeviceType.  Within that view I want a table with each AttributeDefinition as an editable row so that you can update each AttributeDefinition on the same page.

I tried to follow [this post](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/09/07/building-forms-for-deep-view-model-graphs-in-asp-net-mvc/), however I get this error:

> The EntityCollection has already been initialized. The
>   InitializeRelatedCollection method should only be called to initialize
>   a new EntityCollection during deserialization of an object graph.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to something like AutoMapper?  Maybe using the FormCollection or using a ViewModel?

Comment: The error you are getting seems to be related to the way you are fetching your data. It has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - You are right, however it seems to be occuring when the framework attempts to create the models to pass back to the post Edit function which I have no control over as far as I am aware.

Comment: ah alright. Personally I always use view models to and from views in my applications. I try to avoid using data access specific types such as `EntityCollection<T>` in view models. Then I use AutoMapper to do the mapping between my view models and domain models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usualy do not use classes of the namespace `System.Data` in your view model. Change your view model using `List` or another collection class. When you read data from database and you retrieve `EntityCollection`, you need to convert your entity in POCO ojbect and use this new structure as view model.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a single entity/model just for your view. I'm not sure how the  DeviceType and AttributeDefinition are related but your model might look something like this:

```
public class DeviceTypeEditModel
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    String Type { get; set; }
    String Description { get; set; } 
    EntityCollection<AttributeDefinition> AttributeDefinitions { get; set; }
    AttributeDefinition AttributeDefinition { get; set;}
}
```